# Kronecker product source code in TensorLy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorly

I'm trying to understand the code for Kronecker product for tensors implemented in TensorLy. Below is the code:

```
def kron(self, a, b):
    """Kronecker product of two tensors.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a, b : tensor
        The tensors to compute the kronecker product of.

    Returns
    -------
    tensor
    """
    s1, s2 = self.shape(a)
    s3, s4 = self.shape(b)
    a = self.reshape(a, (s1, 1, s2, 1))
    b = self.reshape(b, (1, s3, 1, s4))
    return self.reshape(a * b, (s1 * s3, s2 * s4))
```

I understand that `self.shape(a)` will give the shape of tensor `a` (rows, columns, slices). So we are taking the shape of `a` in `s1` and `s2`, and shape of `b` in `s3` and `s4`.

`a = self.reshape(a, (s1, 1, s2, 1))` reshapes tensor 'a', but I'm finding it difficult to understand what's `(s1, 1, s2, 1)` and why are we doing that? same goes with `(1, s3, 1, s4)`. Also, why are we doing this `self.reshape(a * b, (s1 * s3, s2 * s4))`?.

This might seem as a very open-ended question but I have just started and would love the help!

Comment: FWIW, I don't think your question is especially open ended. I think you've done a good job explaining exactly what you understood and exactly what you need help with.

Comment: That being said, small nitpick: both tensors are clearly 2D. There are no slices involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly common trick using broadcasting. Inserting the unit dimensions into `a` and `b` in that alignment makes the following happen:

1. In the first axis, `b` is replicated `s1` times, to match with each row of `a`.
2. In the second axis, `a` is replicated `s3` times to match with every row of `b`.
3. In the third axis, `b` is replicated `s2` times, to match with each column of `a`.
4. In the fourth axis, `a` is replicated `s4` times, to match with each column of `b`.

When you do the multiplication, you end up with a 4D product of each combination of elements. Element `result[i, j, m, n]` comes from `a[i, m] * b[j, n]` The final reshape takes the same data in memory and combines the first two and last two axes without rearranging the data.

Let's work through a simple example:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [2, 3, 4],
     [3, 4, 5]]
b = [[6, 7]]
```

The shapes are changed from `(3, 3)` and `(1, 2)` to `(3, 1, 3, 1)` and `(1, 1, 1, 2)`. This doesn't change the in-memory layout, so `a` becomes

```
[[[[1], [2], [3]]],
 [[[2], [3], [4]]],
 [[[3], [4], [5]]]]
```

`b` becomes

```
[[[[6, 7]]]]
```

The result will be shaped `(3, 1, 3, 2)`, and will look like this:

```
[[[[1*6, 1*7], [2*6, 2*7], [3*6, 3*7]]],
 [[[2*6, 2*7], [3*6, 3*7], [4*6, 4*7]]],
 [[[3*6, 3*7], [4*6, 4*7], [5*6, 5*7]]]]
```

When you reshape this into the final result, the memory layout stays the same, but the shape changes to `(3*1, 3*2)`:

```
[[1*6, 1*7, 2*6, 2*7, 3*6, 3*7],
 [2*6, 2*7, 3*6, 3*7, 4*6, 4*7],
 [3*6, 3*7, 4*6, 4*7, 5*6, 5*7]]
```

And voila, behold the Kronecker product of `a` and `b`.

Comment: this is an excellent answer. Cleared all my doubts, I was stuck since two days. Thank you so much. You're amazing.

Comment: @Jean, amazing!